# UIButton Title Label Text Not Changing Using Storyboard or Programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, xcode-storyboard

Xcode 12.0.1

I am trying to remove the title label text on a UIButton using the storyboard.  I then plan on setting it programmatically.  When removing the text via the storyboard, the preview shows the text removed.  However, the text remains when I build and run the application.

[image: original text]

[image: text removed]

[image]

Changing programmatically is not working either.  I try to change in in the controllers viewDidLoad()

```
            punchBtn.setTitle("Transfer", for: .normal)
            punchBtn.setTitle("Transfer", for: .application)
            punchBtn.setTitle("Transfer", for: .selected)
            punchBtn.setTitle("Transfer", for: .reserved)
            punchBtn.setTitle("Transfer", for: .highlighted)
            punchBtn.setTitle("Transfer", for: .disabled)
            punchBtn.setTitle("Transfer", for: .focused)
```

The interesting thing is the text is changing when the button is selected:

[image: button selected]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should do a full-text search for "punch". Maybe there is some duplicate button laying around, or you didn't press the _Enter_ key after deleting the text.

Comment: Try my answer, that is work for me

Answer (score 1):

In the file Main.strings you will find this word "punch".
change it from there or else take a new button.

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like a cache issue, because nowhere in the app does it say "Punch" anymore.
Command-Shift-K to clean the project hopefully fixes that.

If that doesn't work, then search the entire workspace for instances where you used the word "punch".

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // other code
    // end of method
    // Change the text of your button
}
```